# C# Alternative window's shell not displaying

Tags: c#, windows, shell

I am writing a very simple alternative shell to replace explorer.exe the shell is run on Windows 10 Enterprise. I set up the C# Windows Form application to display as the alternative shell in the registry and pointed it to the \share folder.

When Windows boots and logs me in I get a black empty screen. If I run explorer.exe through the task manager - I does not load the Shell but the folder explorer. So Windows recognises that an alternative shell is being used.

So why is the form not displaying?

There is no code to show as the form is simply a form with a single label on it saying running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily solved when I thought about it.
Shells cannot be started from a Shared network folder - the executable must be on a local drive.